# Como retornar uma tupla numa função em Haskell?

Tags: string, funções, haskell, tupla

Comecei a mexer com Haskell por conta de uma atividade da faculdade e estou com dúvidas quanto ao que pode ser o erro em meu código. O programa terá duas funções. 'tam', que retornará o tamanho de uma string e `statistics`, que recebe uma `String` e retorna uma tupla do tipo `(String, Int)`:

- A string de retorno será composta pela primeira e última letra da string de entrada separadas por um ponto,  e:
- O inteiro corresponde ao tamanho da string de entrada.

Exemplo de entrada:

```
statistics "carro"

-- Saída
("c.o", 5)
```

Ou:

```
statistics "mala"

-- Saída:
("m.a", 4)
```

O código:

```hs
tam :: [a] -> Int
tam [] = 0
tam ( x:xs ) = 1 + tam xs

tupla :: (Integer, [Char])
statistics :: [Char] -> ([Char], Integer)

statistics string = print $ tupla
  type tupla :: ([Char], Integer)
  where tupla = ( let a = head string; b = '.'; c = last string in a+b+c,
                  tam string)
```

Recebi este erro:

> ```
> parse error on input `type'
> ```

Já tentei de outra forma:

```hs
tam :: [a] -> Int
tam [] = 0
tam ( x:xs ) = 1 + tam xs

statistics :: [Char] -> ([Char], Integer)

statistics string = print $ tupla
  where tupla = (x, y)
  where x = (head string + "." + last string)
  where y = (tam string)
```

Estou recebendo este erro:

> ```
> parse error on input `where'
> ```

Comment: O que não está dando certo? Vale **[edit]** a sua resposta para adicionar mais detalhes sobre o erro. :)

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, você  não precisa de reinventar a roda criando uma função `tam`, já que, como em Haskell strings são listas de caracteres (`Char`), você pode utilizar a função [`length`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:length) em uma string, o que irá retornar o seu comprimento.

Em seguida, a anotação de tipo que você está utilizando para `statistics`:

> ```
> statistics :: [Char] -> ([Char], Integer)
> ```

É incorreta, uma vez que `statistics` retorna o valor da expressão retornada pela função `print`, que é um [`IO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-IO.html) *monad* "vazio". Portanto, a anotação deveria ser:

```
statistics :: [Char] -> IO ()
```

Ou simplesmente não crie essa anotação e deixe o compilador inferir os tipos automaticamente para você (o compilador de Haskell é excelente nesse tipo de coisa).

Há, também, o uso incorreto da cláusula `where`. Não é necessário a repetir, saiba mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740543/is-there-any-way-for-multiple-where-statement-in-haskell). O operador `+` também está sendo erroneamente utilizado, uma vez que só deve ser usado com números, e nesse caso está sendo usado para "concatenar" strings.

Uma solução é simplesmente retornar uma string de caracteres (já que `head` e `last` retornam, em uma string, um `Char`):

```hs
statistics :: String -> IO ()
statistics str = print ([x, '.', y], len)
 where
  x   = head str
  y   = last str
  len = length str
```

Como `[x, '.', y]` é uma lista de três `Char`s, Haskell o interpretará como `String`, isto é, `[Char]`.

Mas o `where` nem é necessário, uma vez que não está evitando nenhum tipo de repetição. Eu pessoalmente só utilizaria para tornar o código mais legível ou evitar repetições, o que não é o caso aqui.

Enfim, você também pode fazer:

```
statistics str = print ([head str, '.', last str], length str)
```

Mas lembre-se que `head` e `last` lançarão uma exceção no caso da lista passada ser vazia. Vale tomar cuidado com isso.